# Jest Puppeteer - How to select second occurrence of a class in a modal?

Tags: css, dom, jestjs, automated-tests, puppeteer

I am currently writing some automated tests with jest-puppeteer. I'm running into a situation where there are two elements with the same classes appearing on the DOM. I am trying to have Puppeteer click the second occurrence, but it keeps clicking the first element!!

Here is a breakdown of my workflow for clarity. 
1. Main page has an element with class `.action-button`.
2. Click on a different button which opens up a modal.
3. Modal has another button with class `.action-button`.
4. I cannot get Puppeteer to click on the second `.action-button` from the modal!!

Here's a snippet of my code.

```
    await page.waitForSelector('.open-modal');

    await page.waitForSelector('.action-button');

    await page.click('.action-button)';
```

How can I have Puppeteer click the second `.action-button`?

***EDIT - SOLUTION***
I swear I tried this earlier, but I must've had a brain fart.

The solution is a simple CSS selector with the a unique parent attribute value and the class that I'm looking for.

```
    await page.waitForSelector('.open-modal');

    await page.waitForSelector('[unique-attr] .action-button');

    await page.click('[unique-attr] .action-button)';
```

Comment: do they have any other attributes that could differentiate besides class?

Comment: The parent element of the second `.action-button` has a unique attribute. I swear I did this earlier, but I just tried this again after taking my dog out to go poop. I had Puppeteer wait for the unique parent element before having it click my button. Must've had one of those infuriated moments where my brain just gets fried...

Answer (score 0):

In Vuejs  we usually do like this
findAll('class-name).at(index)
Where as Index starts from 0  and so on.
So for 2nd occurrence we would something like this
findAll('class-name').at(1)